# Creating FFI between C and my language

Tags: c++, c, ffi, language-implementation, language-binding

Let's say that I have implemented a programming language, (we'll call it **A** for now). **A** is pretty similiar to C.

I want my users to be able to access functions and data structures from already-existing C libraries. Is this possible? If it is, how would a naive implementation look ?

**A**

- is implemented in C++
- compiles to machine code
- needs to access closed-source C libraries

Comment: One naive way is to generate C code from A code

Comment: @Alex Shesterov: This is not an option. Firstly, because **A** compiles to machine code. Secondly, because not all libraries are open-source. I'll update the question. Thanks for the response anyway.

Comment: You'll need a copy of the ABI for each platform that **A** supports, and you'll need to produce object files that the C linker understands.  Searching SO for `[c] ABI` turns up some threads that may be of interest, e.g. [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127874/c-abi-with-llvm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This largely depends on what sort of language *A* is.

If it is a compiled language, then you need to produce appropriate assembler code (look up "calling conventions", particularly the C calling convention) to call the appropriate C function. If you're using LLVM, you can do this fairly easily by using the `declare` and `call` statements. After you've done that, you'll need to link the executable against the C library in question.

If it is an interpreted language, however, then you'll need to dynamically load the library. How you do this is platform-specific: for instance, on unix-type systems, this can be achieved via the `dlopen` function.

Comment: So, LLVM has the functionality to access compiled C libraries built-in?

Comment: @Dundee: yes, see http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#call-instruction - LLVM is something I'd recommend anyway as it implements a decent optimiser for you.

Comment: I wanted to use LLVM anyway, however, I had no idea about this handy feature. I'll definitely use this. Many thanks.